# R and pdf() make figures to breath

Tags: r, pdf, scale, figure

I am using the Gmisc package to plot some state diagrams. The package is great for this purspose but I am stuck with one visualization task when I try to build a very large diagram.

Even though it is hard to see in detail in a large screen all the information, it will be nice to be able to zoom in specific regions and see in more detail what is going on.

The gmisc package does not have parameters for scaling apart of setting width of a box.

The code that plots this diagram is just the following:

```
pdf(file="LargeFigure.pdf")
transitions$render()
dev.off()
```

[image: State diagram where components overlap make them indistinguishable]

Is it possible to inform the pdf device to take as much space is needed so the figure elements never overlap? Of course that will be a large figure where one will need to zoom in to see detail.

I would like to thank you in advance for your reply.
Regards
Alex

Answer (score 0):

I think you can specify the width and height of your graphics region in the pdf file by specifying `width` and `height` options in `pdf()` function. An example

```
pdf(file="LargeFigure.pdf", width = 8, height = 8)
```

The default width and height in `pdf()` function are 7.

Comment: I tried it. The objects still fall one over the other. It does not look that the pdf() can "see " there is space to put things so the overlaps continues. Any more ideas?

Comment: Do you have to use pdf() function? If you want to export the plot, why don't you use jpeg() function in which you can modify resolution to avoid overlapping. As far as I know, we can't modify plot resolution in pdf() function.

Comment: I can use anything that will give me results :) What is modifying resolution then? Changing width and height?

Comment: In jpeg() function, you can modify resolution of the plot using "res" option, you can try higher resolution to reduce overlapping I guess.